# Java Android create file chmod 666

Tags: java, android, permissions, chmod

I can't understand why when saving a file the permissions are not set to 666
Tell me what could be the problem?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
```

java code:

```
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }

            file.createNewFile();
            file.setReadable(true);
            file.setWritable(true);
            file.setWritable(true, false);
            file.setReadable(true, false);



            Set<PosixFilePermission> crunchifyPermissions = new HashSet<>();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                crunchifyPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
                crunchifyPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
                crunchifyPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
                crunchifyPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
                crunchifyPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
                crunchifyPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);
                Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Paths.get(file.getPath()), crunchifyPermissions);
            }
    
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
            BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            bufferWriter.append(content);
            bufferWriter.newLine();
            bufferWriter.close();
```

If I uninstall the app and then install it again. Then, after that, the application does not have access to this file. Despite the fact that I set the rights to 666, they are still set for the user, and not for everyone else.

Comment: POSIX-style file permissions ("666") do not map to Android file permissions and will be ignored by Android. "If I uninstall the app and then install it again. Then, after that, the application does not have access to this file" -- that is expected behavior on Android 11+, as part of scoped storage rules.

Comment: Right. I figured it out after a few days of searching.
It turns out on android 11+ you need to add in the manifest. MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: You may not be allowed to distribute your app with that permission.

Comment: And how then to work with files on android 11+?

Comment: That depends a lot on what you mean by "work with" and what you mean by "files".

Comment: save backup in file

Comment: Use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument`, and allow the user to choose where on the user's device (or in the user's cloud storage) you should place the backup of the user's content.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me. Especially everything was well described in these examples. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/DocumentsSample.java

Comment: same way https://slions.net/threads/access-files-and-documents-on-android.83/